# to run this program you must install .net (for a net5.0 windows forms app windows 11)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, .net-5, windows-forms-core

I built a small C# windows forms project on Windows 11 using net5. It runs fine in debug mode under Vstudio 2019 latest (v16.11.8). If it helps any, the "dotnet --list-sdks" commands report that both .NET v5.0.404 and v6.0.101 are installed."dotnet --list-runtimes" reports that runtimes NETCore.App 3.1.22, 5.0.13, and 6.0.1 are installed, along with WindowsDesktop.App versions 3.1.22, 5.0.13, and 6.0.1.

When I build the app I use the post-build event to copy files to a different folder where I double click the .exe file to run the forms app. But the double click always tells me that to run the app I need to install ".NET" (exactly, no other info). Would you like to download it now? I click Yes, the popup dialog disappears, and nothing happens.

I copied the .exe first to the destination folder, and when that failed I copied the json config file, the DLL, and the .pdb file too. But still, no happiness.

I must be missing something simple since the app runs fine under vstudio.

I compared the contents of the Debug/net5.0-windows folder with my destination folder. The Debug folder had 44 other DLLs and a dozen language packs. I suspect that my .exe app cannot find all those DLLs for some reason. It should find them because of all the SDKs and runtimes that are installed. But I don't know enough about how to tell the .exe file to find and use all the installed SDKs and runtimes.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I can get the exported file to run using the installed runtimes? Thank you.

Comment: You should [publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish) your app to folder. And another useful [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli).

Comment: Thank you! I did the publish operation to a test folder and it copied in all 40 or 50 dependency files. Wow. Not like framework 4.8, where I only had to copy my single executable file. A question please - I'm not deploying this exe on any other machine; it will just run on my dev machine. Is there any way I can copy just the executable and have it find the files somewhere else installed already? Thanks

Comment: After reading up a lot more on dotnet publishing, I see that the published output will always include all the app dependencies. The only alternative is whether or not to include the whole runtime set of assemblies (--self-contained or not). Thank you again for your help in pointing me to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can publish it with a single executable option -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#publish-a-single-file-app---visual-studio

You can do this via VS gui or with the .net cli like:
`dotnet publish -r win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained false`

Comment: It's very strange that "PublishSingleFile=true" is necessary, but I can confirm that this seemed to solve my problem (same as the op issue - dialog asks to install .NET Desktop Runtime, but absolutely no action when clicking "yes").

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's one of those cases where the error message is simply misleading.

Got this message even after having installed the latest .NET 5.0 runtime files.
And even after the suggested `dotnet publish` the application still wouldn't start on the target machine.

Turns out that, **in addition** to the .NET runtime files, there is also a "Windows Desktop Runtime". Only after installing the latter the app would start normally.